# Get masterRequest URL in a fragment controller

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I have made a method called by an Ajax request when a button is clicked.

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @Route("/add", name="rapid_access_add", options={"expose"=true})
 * @Method({"GET"})
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function addRouteAction(Request $request)
{
    $title = $request->query->get('title');
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $url = $this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest()->getUri();

    $rapidAccess = new RapidAccess();
    $rapidAccess->setUrl($url)
        ->setTitle($title)
        ->setUser($user);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($rapidAccess);
    $em->flush();

    $this->addFlash('success', $this->get('translator')->trans('user.flash.rapid_access_added', ['%title%' => $title], 'front'));

    return new Response('OK');
}
```

I'm trying to get the URL of the current page, render by another controller (this method is in a fragment controller).

But when I use `$this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest()->getUri();` this give me the URL of the `addRouteAction` method.

This should give me the master request URL but I don't understand why this send me this method URL. How can I get the current page URL instead of this method URL ?

Maybe I should get the URL with JS instead ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why do use request stack ?

You can use directly `Request` from Controller :

```
$request->getUri();
```

Comment: `Request` gives me the `addRouteAction` URI too. So I tried with request stack

Comment: Have you tried `$request->getRequestUri();` or `$request->getBasePath()` ?

Comment: Yep, `$request->getRequestUri();` gives me the same URL and `$request->getBasePath();` is null

Comment: Ok, so why do you not recovered the URL you want before (in ajax call) and then you send it to addRouteAction to get it like this : `$request->query->get('my_master_url')` ?

Comment: Yes I did like this. This is working well. Thanks you !